# Angularjs $http.get method not working

Tags: javascript, http, angularjs, spring-mvc, get

HI i have a micro service running on port 8501.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/feeds")
public class FeedsController {

    @RequestMapping(method = GET)
    ResponseEntity<?> findAllFeeds() {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello", OK);
    }


}
```

when i add url `http://localhost:8501/feeds`, browser displays "Hello". Now i am trying to access this through angularjs get call

in my AngularJs my code is

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('commentsjsApp');
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {

    $http.jsonp('http://localhost:8501/feeds').success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    console.debug("Data : "+data+ "Status");
}).error(function(){
    console.debug("error");
});
```

EDIT : 
In Network tab (firebug) i can see the GET with 200 status and response is "Hello". Why i am getting the error in console then? Can any one kindly help me.

and when i run this angularjs app. the following output on console as shown in image

[image]

Comment: If your html page is not being served from `localhost:8501`, then I think you are running against restrictions on fetching data across domains. You may need [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or jsonp to transfer your data.

Comment: @musically_ut thanks for response, i have now updated my question. can you kindly check it now

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting a JSONP data, but the server is returning a `string`. Return a proper JSON object from the server to fix the issue.

**Note**: `Hello world` is not valid JSON, but `"Hello World"` is.

Comment: I have Updated the question, as i can see the "Hello" in response (when check it in the network tab of firebug)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in the response, since your calling from localhost:9000 to localhost:8501 (they are technically different servers).

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET)
ResponseEntity<?> findAllFeeds(HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {

    httpResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "http://127.0.0.1:9000");        

    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello", OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Angular requires the colon in the URL to be quoted, try this:

```
$http.get('http://localhost\\:8501/feeds').success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.debug("Data : "+data);
    }).error(function(){
        console.debug("error");
    });
```

Comment: You can try to return properly formatted JSON from server, something like `return new ResponseEntity<String>("{value: 'Hello'}", OK);`.